# The second pattern of a regex not replacing apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a regex that matches straight apostrophes and replaces them with a curly ones. Sometimes an apostrophe goes in the middle of two characters. Other times goes at the end of a character/word (e.g. ellipsis').

So I have two regexes that handle both situations (separated by an or statement).

However, only the first case is being replaced, not the second. In other words, this:

```
"Wor'd word'".replace(/(?<=\w)\'(?=\w)|(?<=\w)\'(?=\s)/, '&rsquo;')
```

Becomes this:

```
"Wor&rsquo;d word'"
```

This confuses me because both types of apostrophes are matching: https://regexr.com/4td7p

Why is this, and how to fix it?

**Update:** I figured the problem was that there's no space after the last apostrophe, so I changed the second part of the regex to this: `(?<=\w)\'(?!\w)` (don't match if there's a character after the apostrophe). But I'm getting the same result.

Comment: You need the global flag, `/g`, else only the first occurrence will be replaced (note how the regexr link's flags contain "g", but your code's pattern doesn't)

Comment: @CertainPerformance adding the `g` doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying for the last `'` to be replaced? It doesn't match because there are no characters after the `'` - lookahead fails because there are no characters ahead. You can lookahead for `\s` or the end of the string, `(?=\s|$)`. You can also put the patterns together instead of alternating, `(?<=\w)\'(?=[\s\w]|$)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance This isn't a `g` flag issue, so it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Check my update. Now I'm saying: "don't match if there's a character ahead." But I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match `(?<=\w)\'` followed by a character and also match `(?<=\w)\'` not followed by a character, why not just drop the logic after it altogether and just use `(?<=\w)'`? (no need to escape `'`s in a regex)

You also need the global flag to replace more than one thing at a time:

```js
console.log(
  "Wor'd word'".replace(/(?<=\w)'/g, '&rsquo;')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why my updated regex `(?<=\w)\'(?!\w)` is not doing the trick.

Comment: Oh ... my first regex wasn't working with the `g`. But my updated regex works with the `g`.

Comment: None of the patterns will work if there is more than one character in the string to replace *and* the `g` flag is not being used. The `g` flag is necessary to replace all matches regardless.

Answer (score -1):

**updated**

```js
var str = "Wor'd word' that's a good thing'";
var afterReplace = str.replace(/'\b/g, '&rsquo;') 
console.log(afterReplace);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why my updated regex `(?<=\w)\'(?!\w)` is not doing the trick.